# Filtering Django Databases

Tags: database, django, django-templates, django-views

I am learning Django and am trying to filter names based off the database table: `power_id`. Is there anyway to filter based off `power_id`, or any variable in a database? Here is what I have so far. Note, I am using Twitter-Bootstrap

This is the Team View

```
<div class="accordion-inner">
    <ul>
        {% if User.object.power_id == 1 %}
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                {{ user }}
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Lets say, 1 is an Admin.

Here is my views.py:

```
# Home view
class home(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'users/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'User_list'
    context_object_name2 = 'Power_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.order_by('username')

# Team view
class team(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'users/team.html'
    context_object_name = 'User_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.order_by('username')

    context_object_name2 = 'Power_list' 
    def in_catagory(User, Admin):
        return things.filter(Admin=Admin)
```

Comment: I do not really understand the question, and its way to early for you to be using generic views right now. Work with normal views at this point in time, then go onto generic views.

Comment: I am basically have a list of names, each in a certain class. I am trying to display the names based on their class id, or `power_id`. @GamesBrainiac

Comment: Is this a part of the User model?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac no, this is the template and views.py file

Comment: Is there a forloop before this?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac No, this is it. What Should be added, because I have no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, you have passed in a model that you have created called `User`. Now, I do not know if this is a model that you have actually created or if you are using `django.contrib.auth.models.User`. But, this is an attempt to show you how to work with views in django.

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import User


class TeamView(View):

    def get(self, request):

        Users = User.objects.filter(power_id='123')
        return render(request, 'something.html', {'Users': Users, })
```

What I've done here may look intimidating, but is actually quite simple. From what I can understand, you have a bunch of users, with an property called `power_id`. And you want to get that, you need to filter all your users for the users with the `power_id` that you want.

That is what the first line after the `get` function call does. the `get` function call is here because when you send a request to a page, like `www.google.com`, you are sending a `get` request.

Now, the `render` function is a shortcut function. What it does is this: first parameter is always `request`, the second parameter is the html file that you want it to render, and the third parameter is the information you are sending which is a dictionary.

Now coming to your template. You can simply loop through all your users, like so:

```
<div class="accordion-inner">
    <ul>
        {% for user in Users %}
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                {{ user }}
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `get_context_data` method to add that other variable.

```
class TeamView(ListView):
    template_name = 'users/team.html'
    context_object_name = 'User_list'
    model = User # You never set the model

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super('TeamView', self).get_queryset().order_by('username') # call the parent function

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super('TeamView', self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['Power_list'] = self.get_queryset().filter(power_id=1)
        return context
```

Now you also have a context variable `Power_list` with all of the users that have `power_id == 1` that you can iterate over

```
<div class="accordion-inner">
    <ul>
        {% for user in Power_list %}
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                {{ user }}
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I have found the answer to my own question. Turns out, it was much simpler than I thought it was. What I needed was to re-arrange the code, along with getting variables right.

```
<div class="accordion-inner">
    <ul>
        {% for name in User_list %}
            {% if name.power_id == 1 %}
                    <a href="#">{{ name }}</a><br />
                    {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

The views.py file didn't need to be edited at all.

Comment: What? This is very inefficient. You are getting everything in the database just to display 1 record.

Comment: @karthikr: I was trying to tell him that. Django templates are slow enough as it is. Also using generic views this early on is not a good idea.